# Assemble back a momentary switch

Tags: switches, components, pc, cable-assemblies, mechanical-assembly

I have this momentary switch that is used as a Reset switch on my computer :
[image]

I opened it and I'd like to assemble it back.

It's made with these parts:

- the push button
- the grey "frame"
- a spring
- a hard "wire" in J-shape
- 2 small "clamp clips" that are, let's say "rectangular"
- the black base connected to the cable

The problem is that I can't find any schematic on how this switch is assembled to be able to reassemble it. Can you help me?

*I suppose that the spring goes on the "rounded" splitted plastic pin on the base (even the pin seems to be a bit large for the spring diameter, and the 2 "clamp clips" seems to go on perfectly dimensionned places on each side of the button, sliding straight down on the metal part connected to the wire when the button is pushed (but only one of these "extruded" metal parts is clearly visible).*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

With the button mounted on the base :
[image: With button mounted]
[image: With button mounted]

**EDIT 2020.04.14**

Here are some pictures of how I suppose the things go together.
But saying that, I don't see the point of putting the 2 small clamps on each side of the button, as there is one of them that contact nothing else than plastic. And I suppose that the other one, that slides on the visible metal part connected to one wire, cannot contact anything as the second metal part is almost (if not totally) flush with the plastic bottom, and more there is a tiny plastic part under the clamp, to hold it into the button, that should avoid any possible contact.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clips slide on the metal part in the base to control the flow of electricity, they somehow fit into the moving part of the button,

the spring goes inside the bottom of the moving part.

the J shape goes under the moving part and the spring and hooks back onto the slopy staircase part of the moving part with its short end. the long end hooks into the hole and goes under the spring.

the grey frame holds everything together.

"staircase"
[image]

hook position

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think I figured it out for the clamps, at least for one of them. OK for the spring. But I don't understand what you mean for the J shape part. I updated the question with more pictures at this stage, is this what you meant ?

Comment: thanks for the photos.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried this after your previous explanations, but it didn't work (no grip on the button). But... when I tried, the small leg of the wire was into the hole of the spring. Does it go there, or do I have to put it after the spring ?

Comment: Waiting for you answer, I tried mouting it as said just before (short leg after the spring, near the border, and long leg on the button's stairs). That's ok, but I don't have the click sound when pushing the button, as if it was not there.

Comment: I rthink the long leg goes under the spring between the halves of the mound

Comment: And stops after the spring ? Or in the center of the spring ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  whatever fits.